# @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp is not working with LocalDateTime

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, java-8

I am trying to use `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` with `LocalDateTime` type, but it is giving me `org.hibernate.HibernateException:` Unsupported property type for generator annotation `@CreationTimestamp` exception.

I am using 5.0.12.hibernate version with java 8 `LocalDataTime`,

Is there any way to use `@UpdateTimestamp` and `@CreationTimestamp` with Java 8 `LocalDateTime` ?

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unsupported property type for generator annotation @CreationTimestamp
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.godigit.MotorDataService.main(MotorDataService.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unsupported property type for generator annotation @CreationTimestamp
    at org.hibernate.tuple.CreationTimestampGeneration.initialize(CreationTimestampGeneration.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.CreationTimestampGeneration.initialize(CreationTimestampGeneration.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.instantiateAndInitializeValueGeneration(PropertyBinder.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.getValueGenerationFromAnnotation(PropertyBinder.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.getValueGenerationFromAnnotations(PropertyBinder.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.determineValueGenerationStrategy(PropertyBinder.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makeProperty(PropertyBinder.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2225)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:738)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why do you want to struggle with this. Just add 2 Fields for you POJO creation date time and updated Date time. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is your Hibernate version. You need to upgrade it to version 5.2.3 in order to use `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` with `LocalDateTime`. For more information, you can check this [blog](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-creation-update-timestamps-hibernate/). Just upgrade your Hibernate and everything should work as expected.

If you don't want to update your Hibernate version, you can change your field types to one of the following.

- java.util.Date
- java.util.Calendar
- java.sql.Date
- java.sql.Time
- java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: I am using Hibernate 5.4.14.Final version and I still have the same problem

Comment: @VinayaNayak : make sure you don't have another annotation overriding the type of your column.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using some other Date import instead of java.utils

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).